# Codeigniter Can't Connect to SQL Server

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database, codeigniter

Put my file in xampp and run but it shows error : PHP error occurred .
Severity: 8192

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project_live/system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_driver.php:91 
Stack trace: #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project_live/system/database/DB_driver.php(115): CI_DB_mysql_driver->db_pconnect()
 #1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project_live/system/database/DB.php(148): CI_DB_driver->initialize() 
 #2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project_live/system/core/Loader.php(346): DB(Array, NULL) 
 #3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project_live/system/core/Loader.php(1171): CI_Loader->database()
 #4 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project_live/system/core/Loader.php(152): CI_Loader->_ci_autoloader()
 #5 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project_live/system/core/Controller.php(51): CI_Loader->initialize() 
 #6 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project_live/application/controllers/site.php(6): CI_Controller->__construct() 
 #7 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project_live/system/core/C in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project_live/system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_driver.php on line 91
```

Comment: Which file you have modified ? can you post the code which you have tried ?

Comment: Actually it a complete APP when i run it it shows error that i shared.

Comment: Does your file include the required MySQL declarations? Do you have the library properly installed?

Comment: Without seeing your code, we can't provide you any suggestions for help

Comment: All the MySQL Declaration & library functions are done in a proper way because this was run on live server properly but on local it shows error.